# get the last row of which one of its column value is less than the rows of interest within a set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is kind of hard to explain so I'll break it down...Here's the objective

Suppose you have a table

```
ID | Weight

1     2
2     4
3     8
4     66
5     11 
6     44
7     33
```

And suppose I have a set of interested IDs, say (3,4)

My objective is to get two other rows (one for each of the two interested IDs) such that the row that matches with the interested ID has a weight that is one level less than the weight of the interested ID

so in this case

for id 3, we want to return row with ID 2 and weight 4 since row id 2 is the first row of which the weight (4) is less than the weight of row id 3 (8)

for id 4, we want to return row with id 6 and weight 44 since row id 6 is the first row of which the weight (44) is less than the weight of row id 4 (66)

How would you accomplish this with mysql in one single query whereby we use the IN() notation for the interested IDs.....

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, could you tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to propose the following (used ourtable as table name obviously)

```
SELECT id,weight FROM ourtable WHERE weight IN (SELECT MAX(t.weight) FROM ourtable t,ourtable t2 WHERE t.weight < t2.weight && t2.id IN (3,4) GROUP BY t2.id);
```

it gives the following result

```
+----+--------+
| id | weight |
+----+--------+
|  2 |      4 |
|  6 |     44 |
+----+--------+
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You could solving this selecting the first row of a selection of the rows ordered by weight desc which weight is lower than the given weight, in this case for mysql something like:

```
select * from t where weight < (select weight from t where id = :id) order by weight desc limit 1
```

in a in statement following the idea above, you could have something like:

```
select * from (select id, (select weight from t where weight < (select weight from t where id = tp.id) order by weight desc limit 1) from t tp) a where id in (3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution w/o subquery:

```
select w1.id,w1.weight,
left(group_concat(w2.id order by w2.id desc ),LOCATE(',', group_concat(w2.id order by w2.id desc ))-1) as w2_id,
left(group_concat(w2.weight order by w2.weight desc ),LOCATE(',', group_concat(w2.weight order by w2.weight desc ))-1) as w2_weight

from weight as w1, weight as w2 
where w2.weight < w1.weight
and w1.id in (3,4)
group by w1.id
```